# Can only connect to sql server express 2012 via named pipes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have sql server express 2012 installed on windows 2008, locally everything works just fine i can connect via tcpip and named pipes.  Remotely i can connect with ssms **only** using named pipes. By remote i mean within the same LAN, they are plugged into the same switch.

I have tried disabling the firewall on both sides to eliminate blocking traffic. i have toggled the tcpip setting on and off (i read somewhere that they got it working just but flipping them off and back on).  I have double/triple checked all the settings that i'm aware of and everything seems to be correct.

- Tcp is enabled
- Tcp port is set to 1433, udp port is set to 1434
- Server has static ip
- Start up log says: ***Server is listening on [ 'any'  1433].***
- Firewall rules are in place

Any suggestions on things that i can look into? 
i have really just run out of ideas.

**EDIT**: I used to have a copy of sql server 2008 installed on this box before i switched over to 2012.  I uninstalled 2008 and then installed 2012 express; not sure if this changes anything but its another part of the puzzle.

**EDIT #2**: Here is the error message that i from a .net application that is trying to connect remotely.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)]

**EDIT #3**: it looks like this is something that breaks when you install visual studio 11 or more likely .net 4.5, at least for some people; which i just did as well. [Connection error after installing VS 11](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323/visual-studio-11-beta-installation-disabled-my-abillity-to-connect-remote-ms-sql-server-but-not-local-databases) And some more [details](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vssetup/thread/2d11b6f9-3ada-4682-b643-c721a97af4ba)

Comment: Might look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: @ShawnMelton thanks, i found this and went over it as well, but i still tried it again just now with no luck.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11853321

Comment: When you say "remote"... how remote is "remote"? Is the box at a services provider like RackSpace? It is over a WAN link? Or by remote do you just mean from your PC to a server on the LAN?

Comment: @Mark at this time its just remote over the LAN.

Comment: Can you open up Protocols for SQLEXPRESS, click Properties on TCPIP, and get us all the settings in there? Also, is the Browser Service running?

Comment: could you provide the `netstat -an | find "1433"` output as well? Oh, and have you considered disabling encryption on your connection for testing purposes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It seems to be ssl related - maybe the certificate need to be renewed: http://thesqldude.com/2012/04/21/setting-up-ssl-encryption-for-sql-server-using-certificates-issues-tips-tricks/

Comment: Thanks everyone, i had tried all the standard things including even trying to disable encryption; swapping ports, anything i could think of. i did find what the problem was and was able to correct it.  I will write up a proper update that details the resolution.

Comment: Any hope of getting a quick summary of your solution? Answering your own question and closing it will help others.

Comment: How do you resolve this?

Comment: Comments on the linked article suggest a non-IFS LSP/BSP involvement (a custom windows plugin for the network layer stack component, usually panda anti-virus, or some network tool such as the stuff that shipped in Visual Studio 11 beta, which broke core TCP/IP network capabilities on some people's computers).  In my case it was the answer below (misconfigured TCP port settings on the server).

Answer (score 1):

Check the TCP IP setting properties in COnfiguration Manager, the IPAll should set the dynamic to be empty and static to 1433.

Comment: What is the "IPAII?"